# Angular : navigation error with named router outlet when using lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router-outlet

I have a navigation error with named router outlet that occurs only when i use a lazy loaded module.

If i set the module to be eager loaded the problem disappears.

I have published an test Angular application which reproduces the problem (https://github.com/fk-fgs/test-aux-router-outlet-with-lazy-loading) :

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Feature1Module } from './modules/feature1/features1.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Feature1Module,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/feature1/page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'feature2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/feature2/features2.module').then((m) => m.Feature2Module)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p>app component</p>

<p>primary router outlet navigation :</p>
<button routerLink="/feature1/page1">feature1 page1</button>
<button routerLink="/feature2/page1">feature2 page1</button>

<p>aux1 router outlet navigation :</p>
<button [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { aux1: ['feature1', 'page2'] }}]">feature1 page2</button>
<button [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { aux1: ['feature2', 'page2'] }}]">feature2 page2</button>

<div class="router-outlet">
    <p>primary router outlet :</p>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="router-outlet">
    <p>aux1 router outlet :</p>
    <router-outlet name="aux1"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**feature1-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Feature1Page1Component } from './pages/page1/feature1-page1.component';
import { Feature1Page2Component } from './pages/page2/feature1-page2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'feature1/page1', component: Feature1Page1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'feature1/page2', component: Feature1Page2Component,
    outlet: 'aux1'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class Feature1RoutingModule {}
```

**feature2-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Feature2Page1Component } from './pages/page1/feature2-page1.component';
import { Feature2Page2Component } from './pages/page2/feature2-page2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'page1', component: Feature2Page1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'page2', component: Feature2Page2Component,
    outlet: 'aux1'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class Feature2RoutingModule {}
```

**Feature1 and feature2 modules are functionally identical :**

- A component page1 with a route to primary router outlet.
- A component page2 with a route to named aux1 router outlet.

**Feature1 module is eager loaded :**

- No navigation problem.

**Feature2 module is lazy loaded :**

- page1 navigation works.
- page2 navigation does not work and produces an error :

core.mjs:6494 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'feature2/page2'

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'feature2/page2'

at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:2939:16)

at router.mjs:2921:28

at catchError.js:10:38

at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:1)

at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)

at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)

at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)

at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)

at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)

at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)

at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:1)

at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:1)

at zone.js:1278:1

at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)

at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25595:1)

at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)

at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)

at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1)

at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:1)

at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:1)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you. I've never used Angular but I played a bit with your code and I think your problem right now is in your **app.component.html**

You should change your line 9 to :

```
<button [routerLink]="['/feature2', { outlets: { aux1: ['page2'] }}]">feature2 page2</button>
```

After that you will have a new error, **Cannot activate an already activated outlet** which is beyond my knowledge right now in Angular but you should find a solution somewhere here.

To prove that my solution works you can add another `<router-outlet name="aux2"></router-outlet>` in your **app.component.html** and change the outlet in the button for *aux2* and in the route configuration in **feature2-routing.module.ts**.

When you'll click on the button you'll see the result appear.

Good luck ;)